# Connecting Java client to Hazelcast-Kubernetes fails

Tags: java, client, cluster-computing, kubernetes, hazelcast

I'm running a kubernetes cluster in which I am deploying a "cloud native hazelcast" following the instructions on the [kubernetes-hazelcast github page](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/hazelcast). Once I have a number of hazelcast instances running, I try to connect a java client to one of the instances but for some reason the connection fails.

#### Some background

Using a kubernetes external endpoint I can connect to hazelcast from outside the kubernetes cluster. When I do a REST call with `curl kubernetes-master:32469/hazelcast/rest/cluster`, I get a correct response from hazelcast with it's cluster information. So I know my endpoint works.

The hazelcast-kubernetes deployment uses the [hazelcast-kubernetes-bootstrapper](https://github.com/pires/hazelcast-kubernetes-bootstrapper) which allows some configuration by setting environment variables with the replication controller, but I'm using all defaults. So my group and password are "someGroup" and "someSecret".

#### The java client

My Java client code is really straightforward:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setConnectionAttemptLimit(0);
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setConnectionTimeout(10000);
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setConnectionAttemptPeriod(2000);
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("kubernetes-master:32469");
clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName("someGroup");
clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setPassword("someSecret")
HazelcastInstance client = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
```

When start my client this is the log output of the hazelcast container

```
2016-07-05 12:54:38.143  INFO 5 --- [thread-Acceptor] com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.SocketAcceptor     : [172.16.15.4]:5701 [someGroup] [3.5.2] Accepting socket connection from /172.16.29.0:54333
2016-07-05 12:54:38.143  INFO 5 --- [        cached4] c.h.nio.tcp.TcpIpConnectionManager       : [172.16.15.4]:5701 [someGroup] [3.5.2] Established socket connection between /172.16.15.4:5701
2016-07-05 12:54:38.157  INFO 5 --- [.IO.thread-in-1] c.h.nio.tcp.SocketClientMessageReader    : [172.16.15.4]:5701 [someGroup] [3.5.2] Unknown client type: <
```

And the console output of the client

```
jul 05, 2016 2:54:37 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_someGroup][3.6.2] is STARTING
jul 05, 2016 2:54:38 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_someGroup][3.6.2] is STARTED
jul 05, 2016 2:54:48 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 1 of 2147483647.
jul 05, 2016 2:54:58 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
WARNING: Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 2 of 2147483647.
jul 05, 2016 2:55:08 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport
etc...
```

The client just keeps trying to connect but no connection is ever established.

#### What am I missing?

So why won't my client connect to the hazelcast instance? Is it some configuration part I'm missing?

Comment: I haven't worked on kubernetes. But looking at the console logs, any specific reason to have different Hazelcast versions between Node and Client?  Can you update both to be 3.6.4 the latest or just change the cluster to be 3.6.2 to match with client.

Comment: Ha, that's amazing. I didn't think that a newer client talking to an older server would be a problem. But that was it, matching the versions works. Many thanks. (If you post your comment as an answer I will upvote it)

Comment: Glad it worked. Yeah, 3.6.x has lot of configuration changes n bug fixes.

Comment: I would suggest to use official hazelcast discovery plugin for kubernetes https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the console logs, you have different Hazelcast versions between Node and Client? Can you either update both to be 3.6.4 i.e., the latest or just change the cluster to be 3.6.2 to match with client. 3.6.x has many configuration changes and many bug fixes as well.

Comment: This is not a problems because Hazelcast has patch version compatibility (3.6.2 client will work with 3.6.4 cluster). Since 3.6 Hazelcast introduces minor version compatibility. Going forward you will be able to connect 3.6.x to 3.7.x cluster and vice versa.

Comment: That's great. Thanks Vik.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the official kubernetes support, however Hazelcast has a kubernetes discovery plugin (based on the new discovery spi) that works on both, client and nodes: https://github.com/noctarius/hazelcast-kubernetes-discovery

Comment: Hi, this URL returns 404.  Has this official plugin moved somewhere else? (I couldn't find it when browsing the Hazelcast repos).  Thanks, Rob.

Comment: Fixed it for now, still in my own repo, sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No problem. Thank you for putting the effort into the plugin (I wanted to check that I was looking at the right repo ).  Cheers, Rob.